# exim queue notification if a domain is sending more than x number of emails

Tags: spam, exim, csf

I am running Exim as an MTA. I have also implemented a Per hour Per domain email Limit. Still I see that my IP reputation goes bad if a spammer sends more than x amount of emails in 24 hours or so.

I want to setup a notification email so that if a compromised email account or a php script uses exim and sends spam and damages my IP reputation.

This may be an script or CSF which reads exim logs and check how many emails have been sent from a domain and send a notification if sent emails reach X number.

Comment: How exactly you have implemented the ratelimits? Show some `exim`'s configs.

Comment: I have setup rate limit in cpanel. The rate limit is working but still one can send email according to rate limit and blacklist the ip. Suppose two email accounts of two local domains are compromised and the spammer starts sending maximum emails according to rate limit still he can blacklist my ip by sending spam emails to hotmail.